# Double (Scheduler) bean initialization

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, web-config

I have 2 contexts in my application, one is "spring" (Web+MVC), second is "rpc" (just RPC service). Both of them inherits configs from the "spring" directory (there are  4 files: app-config.xml, infrastructure-config.xml, integration-config.xml and security-config.xml).

The app-config.xml contains initialization of the Quartz Scheduler.

So, if I starts my application, there are two Quartz Scheduler threads and all scheduled services are invoked twice. Is that because I inheriting settings from app-confix.xml into both contexts ?

I thought that beans deffined in parent config are initialized only once and shared between context which inheriting that parent config.

Thanks for any advice :).

Example from my web.xml.

```
<context-param>
    <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
    <param-value>
        /WEB-INF/spring/*-config.xml
    </param-value>
</context-param>

<servlet>
    <servlet-name>rpc</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
    <load-on-startup>0</load-on-startup>
</servlet>

<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>rpc</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/rpc/*</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>

<servlet>
    <servlet-name>spring</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>

<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>spring</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/web/*</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your configuration two independent contexts are getting created. Just the fact that they use the same files doesn't cause spring to create a common parent context.

What you need to do is setup a contextLoaderListener in the web.xml - give it the common config file and then exclude it from the servlets config.  The Listener will create the root context and bind it to the servlet context - both the servlets will then link to that as the parent context.

Comment: Thank you, I will try that. I discovered another strange thing. If I run this app directly from eclipse (STS) in debug mode, There is only one schleduler (Quartz) instance . Same configs, same tomcat, but in dev environment is only one bean instance.